3D scatterplot, matrix operations and calculation of the inverse
I have a scatter-plot with the code shown below.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
z = np.random.rand(100)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')
plt.show()

We can say
A = np.column_stack((x, y, z)).

Additionally, I have a matrix B, which equals the matrix A times a rotation operation, a shift operation + noise.
B = A x rot(X) + shift(Y) + Noise

If only matrix A and B are given, how can I find the necessary rotation angle and shift vector to overlap matrix B with matrix A / revert the operations on matrix B? Is a center of mass approach best or what would be the recommended approach?

hard to say.. It probably depends heavily on your type of data. The keyword you're looking for is Point-set registration. There's a decent video from the YouTube channel Computerphile on the Iterative Closest Point (ICP) algorithm.

It is 3D electron diffraction data: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_diffraction
